# Notification When NSApplication receives 'miniaturizeAll' call

Tags: macos, cocoa, hide, objective-c-2.0, nsapplication

Is this possible, like when you call 'hide:' it calls 'applicationWillHide:'?

My application uses a variable amount of windows, depending on the amount of available screens, so it doesn't miniaturize those NSWindow instances when 'miniaturizeAll:' is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSWindowWillMiniaturizeNotification** is one answer. 
It would be sent for each window. 
You could handle it with that.

You could also override:
`- (void)miniaturizeAll:(id)sender`
In an **NSApplication** category ( to avoid subclassing ) and call super if its ok to do so based on your conditions. 
Don't call super if you want to prevent it. ( but do notify users visually )

You might even set the menu item inactive when conditions match your needs, if you create a property you can bind it to.

Comment: Oh a category is probably the way to go in my case, thank you very much uchuugaka. Nice answer!